# What does the word 'Select' represent on the python console?

Tags: windows-console

I am running various python scripts that connect to various sockets to ingest incoming data from a stream. I have noticed that sometimes these scripts hang indefinitely.

It may be of no significance but where **'C:\python27\python.exe'** is usually seen as the window title, it reads **'Select C:\python27\python.exe'**.

Does anyone know what the word **'Select'** represents in this instance?

Is it related to the reason my scripts are crashing - i.e. the word **'Select'** implying that the script is waiting for I/O completion?

I have never noticed this before. Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means you have clicked on the console window with your mouse (probably without meaning to) and have initiated a mark-copy action.

This is actually quite important to know because it freezes your screen output until you finish or cancel it by pressing Escape.

Answer (score 1):

This is really related to the Windows console host, not Python.

The Windows console host shows "Select ..." in the title when it's in selection/marking mode, i.e. after you have dragged with the cursor to select some text, or maybe after hitting shift+up/down to start selecting something.

During selection mode, IO onto the console is paused or buffered, so that might indeed be the cause for crashing.

Comment: That is exactly what was causing the stream to crash. Can't believe I did not know this. Will look to write more robust code I think. Thanks.